# Power BI RLS with Distribution List not working

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

I have a Powerbi report which has RLS Implement through a dimension table
I have created Roles with individual email ID and user principal name and this seems to be working perfectly well .
however when I want to add close to 600 users, I have created a Distribution list And when I put the DL in the role it does not seem to work.
All the users have premium subscription.
Any pointers here will be much appreciated

Comment: You can add a member to the role by typing in the email address, or name, of the user, security group or distribution list you want to add. This member has to be within your organization. Here, security group means Office 365 security group. Please contact with Office 365 administrator to create security group for these 600 members. This way, you don't need to type 600 email addresses to the role, just type security group or distribution list instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input .the admin has confirmed that he has added these users .One another interesting fact here ( should have mentioned earlier ) is that all of them are on G-Suit and not in outlook .not sure if gmail ID’s are not compatible with azure active directory and is creating the issue .any thoughts ?

Comment: Check these two topics:
this from (2018)
The Production Team replied me that "Microsoft does not have any specific code in these products to support G-Suite (or any equivalent software like Okta, etc.)".

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Need-to-know-if-G-suite-users-can-login-to-Power-BI-service/td-p/517704
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Question-about-Single-Sign-on-SSO-from-G-Suite-to-Organizational/m-p/1201171

Comment: Thank you, I have raised a ticket .. will keep posted